# XSLT format-number transform percent

Tags: xslt

Given the XML:

```
<current rate="0.1412" />
```

The desired output to screen is:

```
14.1200%
```

However, the current transform:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(current/@rate, '###,##0.0000')"/>%
```

Yields the output:

```
0.1412%
```

Is it possible to do a format-number transform that will output a value in the desired format (four decimal places) given the current XML input or does it require a change in the xml input to better match the expected output?

Say:

```
<current rate="0.141200" />
```

Comment: You can use `format-number(current/@rate * 100, '###,##0.0000')` to obtain the correct percentage.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to multiply or use any other tricks - just tell the format-number() function you want the number to be formatted as percent:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(current/@rate, '#,##0.0000%')"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

If your rate is being stored as a decimal, then you will need to multiple by 100 to show it as a percentage:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(current/@rate * 100, '###,##0.0000')"/>%
```

Comment: +1 Didn't realize I could multiply inside the function. Thanks!